# Understanding Complex Scope in Javascript Modules and Plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I know there's a lot of questions on Stack about JS Scope... but I ran into a specific problem that I'm unable to wrap my head around. I have a Javascript module that looks something like this (albeit dramatically simplified):

```
module.exports = {
  $company: $('#id_company'),
  $companyCtrl: null,
  $jobType: $('#id_job_type'),
  $jobTypeCtrl: null,

  init: function() {
    var _this = this;
    this.$companyCtrl = this.$company.selectize({
      onChange: function(value) {
        _this.companyChanged(value);
      }
    })[0].selectize;
  },

  companyChanged: function() {
    // Company changed has been fired and does a few things
    // before it calls this:
    this.updateJobType();
  },

  updateJobType: function() {
    var _this = this;
    $.ajax({
      url:'/ajax-url',
      data: {
        'id': this.companyID
      }
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      // If our job type selectize() instance hasn't been setup,
      // then create it now
      if (_this.$jobTypeCtrl === null) {
        // ------------
        // PROBLEM BLOCK 
        _this.$jobTypeCtrl = _this.$jobType.selectize({
          onChange: function(value) {
            if (_this.currentModel !== 'wire_add') {
              _this.jobTypeChanged(value);
            }
          }
        })[0].selectize;
        // ------------
      }

      // Reload and re-enable input
      _this.$jobTypeCtrl.reloadFromOriginalInput();
      _this.$jobTypeCtrl.enable();
    });
  },
}
```

Now, here's what I don't understand, if I move that "PROBLEM BLOCK" outside of the Ajax call, and put it back up into init(), it works fine. However, as far as I can tell, in it's *current location*, the *scope* (_this = this) is the *exact same* as it would be up in the init function.

And to be more specific, the problem I'm experiencing is that the "onChange" handler never fires when the code is inside of the Ajax handler, *but the plugin instance is still created and functions as it otherwise should*. However, if I move it up to the init(), the onChange handler fires without any other changes to the code

Any help to get me to wrap my head around this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue, where you start chasing your own tail using objects.

The power of using modules, is that they have their own context. So once compiled, the file knows what vars and funcs are residing inside; this negates the need to track `this` bouncing from function to function, which becomes a nightmare, once you involve async callbacks.

I recommend rewriting your module with vars at the top and functions, so it's easier to call any function without trying to pass the correct `_this/self` context from here, there and everywhere.

Here's an untested re-write:

```
module.exports = {
  var $company = $('#id_company'),
      $companyCtrl = null,
      $jobType = $('#id_job_type'),
      $jobTypeCtrl = null;

function init() {
    $companyCtrl = $company.selectize({
      onChange: function(value) {
        companyChanged(value); // <== invoke any function and treat them as black-box code
      }
    })[0].selectize;
}

function companyChanged() {
    // Company changed has been fired and does a few things
    // before it calls this:
    updateJobType();
}

function updateJobType() {
    $.ajax({
      url:'/ajax-url',
      data: {
        'id': companyID
      }
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      // If our job type selectize() instance hasn't been setup,
      // then create it now
      if ($jobTypeCtrl === null) {
        // ------------
        // PROBLEM BLOCK 
        $jobTypeCtrl = $jobType.selectize({
          onChange: function(value) {
            if (currentModel !== 'wire_add') {
              jobTypeChanged(value);
            }
          }
        })[0].selectize;
        // ------------
      }

      // Reload and re-enable input
      $jobTypeCtrl.reloadFromOriginalInput();
      $jobTypeCtrl.enable();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Also wanted to add that it's easier to use `bind`, `call` and/or `apply` when invoking a function with a different context, rather than caching `this` with a hacky var like `self`, `_this`, `that`, etc

Comment: My only question would be, the "module.exports" should be something more like this, right:

`module.exports = init;`

?

Comment: Almost, it would be: `module.exports = init;` i.e. without the parenthesis. Edit, you changed your comment whilst i wrote this, so ignore.